# Try to get List of Hospials using Google-places-api

Tags: php

i'm using this api below to find out nearest hospitals.In response json i'm not getting the contact number of those hospitals. how do i get that????
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=22.5531,88.3564&radius=500&types=hospital&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBdBBjxmc51SAqsefefwgwtSyjxT6NPMUAtYA

Comment: Look in the phone book? (Sorry, but this question doesn't appear to have anything to do with programming.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get only thos info which is provided by the api. Please go through this link it has a nice explanation about the apis https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

Answer (score 0):

I think, some of these APIs are closed, so i don't see a solution with Google APIs. Maybe geonames.org or OpenStreetMap gives you a better chance for the data you are looking for.

[Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Dt)